# Parts of ListView in separate Activities/Fragments

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-adapter

Is there a way to have say the first 10 items of a `ListView` in activity/fragment A and then have the next 10 appear in activity/fragment B?

Answer (score 0):

Use Pagination for first 10 element and then after switch the fragment